# Keyboard backlight command by percentage

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard, brightness, backlight

I want to make a keyboard shortcut to increase and the decrease the keyboard backlight brightness.

The command I have for full brightness is:

```
echo -n 100 > /sys/class/leds/chromeos\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

No keyboard led brightness (off):

```
echo -n 0 > /sys/class/leds/chromeos\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

If I wanted to get the current brighness I would:

```
cat /sys/class/leds/chromeos\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Whats the simplest way to increase and decrease the values by a percantage, like 12%. This seems like a fairly common task.

Comment: @Dan: `-n` is an `echo` option, so it does not output a trailing newline. It has nothing to do with the number.

Comment: There are 2 questions here: how to create a script to do calculate (and automate) those commands, and another one on how to assign such scripts to keyboard shortcuts, correct? Since they are pretty distinct and unrelated I suggest you split them in 2 questions, keeping this one for the script (which is the hardest part). The other one I'm sure there are dozens of answers already, just search for it.

Comment: By the way, Chrome OS is not supported in Ask **Ubuntu** :P

Comment: @MestreLion I am running 12.10 on a Chromebook Pixel... the latest 3.10-rc1 kernel just names the driver like that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script to increase and decrease brightness:

```
#!/bin/bash

step=12
file=/sys/class/leds/chromeos\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness

case "$1" in
    -i|--increase) ((val = +step));;
    -d|--decrease) ((val = -step));;
esac

if !((val)); then
    echo "Increase or decrease screen brighness"
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} --increase | --decrease"
    exit
fi

read -r cur < "$file"    
((val = cur + val))

if ((val <   0)); then ((val =   0)); fi
if ((val > 100)); then ((val = 100)); fi

printf '%d' "$val" > "$file"

printf 'Before: %3d\n' "$cur"
printf 'After : %3d\n' "$val"
```

Could be a *lot* simpler for a keyboard shortcut, but I decided to make it a stand-alone script with help and args, just for fun :)

To run:

- save it somewhere, for example `~/keyboard-brightness`
- set execute permission: `chmod +x ~/keyboard-brightness`
- `~/keyboard-brightness --increase`
- `~/keyboard-brightness --decrease`

Now just add them as keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Thanks! I should really get into those more. [In action, pressing repeatedly](https://googledrive.com/host/0BzxXaPUM9KPJNFdOcDl3WjlxaTA/aubucinima.gif)

Comment: So it worked? great! :)

Comment: I tried this script on my pixel running a native Ubuntu 13.10 install, but I end up with the following error: /sys/class/leds/chromeos::kbd_backlight/brightness: No such file or directory any suggestions?

Comment: @user200275: this script was customized for the OP's hardware. Maybe your Chromebook is different. Check the `/sys` tree for a file that looks related to keyboard leds (start with the `/sys/class/leds/chromeos` tree) and change the script accordingly